# Can't display paths for matched nodes with multiple incoming relationships in Cypher

Tags: cypher

I have a Neo4j graph based on this pattern: `(:Entity)-[:HAS_VALUE]->(:Value)-[:HAS_SYNONYM]->(:Synonym)`.
Each Entity can have multiple Values, and each Value can have multiple Synonyms. I'm looking for ambiguous synonyms -- Synonym nodes with more than 1 Value node connected to them.

I can find the offending Synonym nodes as follows:

`MATCH ()-[r:HAS_SYNONYM]->(n) WITH n, count(r) as num_values WHERE num_values > 1 RETURN n`

However, when I try to display the paths (so that I can see the interconnections with the offending Values), the browser gives me "(no changes, no records)". Here are some of the queries I tried:

`MATCH (n1:Value)-[r:HAS_SYNONYM]->(n2:Synonym) WITH n1, n2, r, count(r) as num_values WHERE num_values > 1 RETURN n1, r, n2`

`MATCH (n1)-[r:HAS_SYNONYM]->(n2) WITH n1, n2, r, count(r) as num_values WHERE num_values > 1 RETURN n1, r, n2`

`MATCH p = (n)-[r:HAS_SYNONYM]->() MATCH (n)-[r:HAS_SYNONYM]->() WITH p, n, count(r) as num_values WHERE num_values > 1 RETURN nodes(p)`

Is my syntax wrong, or is it more fundamental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your queries is the `WITH` command. When we write
`WITH n1, n2, r, count(r)`, the count is computed for each distinct combination of `n1`, `n2`, and `r`, which will always be 1, hence you see no changes, no records.
Try calculating the count by `n2` nodes first, then filter the synonyms with `count > 1`, then fetch the paths for those synonyms.

Like this:

```
MATCH (:Value)-[r:HAS_SYNONYM]->(n2:Synonym) WITH n2, count(r) as num_values WHERE num_values > 1 
MATCH (n2)<-[rel:HAS_SYNONYM]-(v:Value)
RETURN v, rel, n2
```

Comment: That did it, alright! I've obviously missed out on some of the subtleties of Cypher in my tutorials and readings.